# Proguard Config File for Multi-Project Android App

Tags: android, proguard

I have a multi-project android application.

Project A has the Activities, but it has dependency on a Project B UI library project (which I also need to obfuscate), and a Project C Service Library(which I also need to obfuscate).  These two jar files (uilib.jar and services.jar),  appear under java build path of Project A as "Android Dependencies" along with a lot of third party libraries like commons.jar etc which I don't need to obfuscate.   I need to know how to specify uilib.jar and services.jar so that these classes will be properly obfuscated.  I would also like to remove all the other jars like common.jar from obfuscation since they are third party open source and I did not write them.  Thanks